# Linq to join two similar object list?

Tags: c#, linq

```
objA = new obj()
{
    ID = 123,
    attriA = "",
    attriB = "someValueB"
}

objB = new obj()
{
    ID = 123,
    attriA = "someValueA",
    attriB = ""
}

List<obj> ListA = new List<obj>();
ListA.add(objA);

List<obj> ListB = new List<obj>();
ListB.add(objB);
```

Given the above scenario, I need to have `listC` with the below object:

```
objC = new obj()
{
    ID = 123,
    attriA = "someValueA",
    attriB = "someBalueB"
}
```

This is what I've tried. It worked but I'm thinking there must be ways to shorten the code by using linQ which I have no idea:

```
foreach(obj item in ListA)
{
    obj objB = ListB.Where(x=> x.ID == item.ID).FirstOrDefault();

    obj objC = new obj(){
        ID = objB.ID;
        attriA = item.attriA;
        attriB = objB.attriB;
    };
    ListC.add(objC);
}
```

Comment: For optimizing or reviewing the code please visit [Codereview.StackExchange](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use linq join as below

```
 var query = from a in ListA
                join b in ListB
                     on a.ID equals b.ID
                select new Obj()
                {
                     ID = b.ID;
                attriA = a.attriA;
             attriB = b.attriB;
                };
```

Above code is not tested

Comment: This would work for this particular scenario but if attribA on obj a is the one without a value and you want attribB instead then it wont.

Answer (score 4):

if there are always strings you can go with something like this:

```
var listC = ListA.Join(ListB, 
            A => A.ID, B => B.ID, 
            (A, B) => new {
                ID = A.ID,
                attriA = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(A.attriA) ? A.attriA : B.attriA,
                attriB = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(B.attriB) ? B.attriB : A.attriB
            });
```